# communicate two android applications

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, aidl

I have two applications but I need you to push a button on the application to the button that has the same application B that change happen. 
  I would greatly appreciate if you give me an idea of ​​how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried using intents?

Comment: the point is true that the two applications by the user of the phone are made. What I would like to make is that since the application can handle A Application B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the examples shown here:
[Interacting with Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)

They explain what you wish to accomplish pretty well.